# React Native View not consisting the Text component which is written in that View as child?

Tags: css, react-native, stylesheet

In the Code you can see that i created a nested View in the Component , and styled the parent View with border Color 'green' and the Child View with the border Color 'yellow'. Child View Contains some Text . My problem is WHY THE TEXT COMPONENT IS NOT INSIDE THE BORDER , you can see the output in the image_2 ?

```
class Header extends React.Component{
     render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.topView}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text>MENUBAR</Text>
                    <Text>TITLE</Text>
                    <Text>HOME</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    topView:{
        backgroundColor : '#87cefa',
        borderColor : 'green',
        borderWidth : 2
    },
    header : {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection : 'row',
        marginTop : '10%',
        backgroundColor : '#FFF000',
        borderColor : 'yellow',
        borderWidth : 3,
        alignSelf : 'stretch'
    }
})
```

Code Input Image :-

[image]

output Image :-

[image]

Comment: the output is in? android? or ios?

Comment: try giving flex:1 in your root container!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the flex:1 to this view:

```
topView:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor : '#87cefa',
    borderColor : 'green',
    borderWidth : 2
},
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing the css to this;

```
 topView:{
        minHeight : 90, // flex: 1 // if  you want it as full screen. 
        backgroundColor : '#87cefa',
        borderColor : 'green',
        borderWidth : 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    header : {
        flexDirection : 'row',
        backgroundColor : '#FFF000',
        borderColor : 'yellow',
        borderWidth : 3,
    }
```

Hope this will help you.